# Is there any relationship between Granger causality and Cross-correlation diagram?

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-correlation, granger-causality

I had plotted Cross Correlation diagram of my bivariate dataset (bonds and equity) and observed that I have significant lag coefficients. This implies that a lag of bonds may explain better the prediction in the equities. However, when I applied the Granger Causality test I fail to reject the null of no Granger Causality.

**Question**: I expected to reject the null why I am not able to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spoke to a great econometrician he informed me the following:

- In Granger test, we factor out the auto-correlation coefficients, and hence we only focus our attention on the cross-correlation coefficients. Therefore, we may find significance in the cross-correlation diagram but not in the Granger test because the cross-correlation does not factor our the auto-correlation.

However, it would be better to test for significance coefficients in the VAR models.